# Override required dependency module exported function

Tags: node.js, node-modules, keycloak

Node.js project uses [keycloak-nodejs-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/releases/tag/v4.3.0) dependency  installed with npm install.

Dependency index.js looks like:

```
 ...
 var GrantManager = require('./middleware/auth-utils/grant-manager');
 ...
 function Keycloak (config, keycloakConfig) {         
     this.config = new Config(keycloakConfig);
     this.grantManager = new GrantManager(this.config);
 ...
 module.exports = Keycloak;
```

**./middleware/auth-utils/grant-manager.js** looks like:

```
...
const Token = require('./token');
....
module.exports = GrantManager;
...
```

**./middleware/auth-utils/token.js** looks like

```
...
Token.prototype.isExpired = function isExpired () {
  return ((this.content.exp * 1000) < Date.now());
};
... 
module.exports = Token;
```

Project source code uses Keycloak module:

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
```

How to override **function isExpired** source code inside the project source code?
The only thing that pops my mind is overriding **token.js** inside **node-modules...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Import `Token` to your project
2. Override `isExpired` method on `Token`'s prototype

```
var Token = require('keycloak-connect/middleware/auth-utils/token')
Token.prototype.isExpired = {
  // your implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions can be:

> You fork 'keycloak-nodejs-connect' git repo made your changes and after 
>   in your package.json put your forked repository.